# Good examples of idiomatic scala code

Tags: scala

Scala is a large and complex language. In my experience, the best way to learn such a language is to read really good code. Are there any open source examples of such code? What can you recommend?

Comment: Take a look at some popular projects [here](https://github.com/languages/scala).

Comment: @missingfaktor : This link is broken. Could you please provide another link ?

Comment: @fahimayat, I wonder if they removed the feature where one can see projects in one specific language.

Comment: @fahimayat You can look at trending github scala projects [here](https://github.com/trending?l=scala&since=monthly).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz). Be aware that it's written in a far more functional style than most Scala code.
2. [Twitter Util](https://github.com/twitter/util) (already mentioned in @axel22's answer).

Answer (score 8):

The [Scala standard library](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/master/src/library) should be pretty idiomatic in most places. The [Scala Swing library](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/master/src/swing/scala/swing) is another example.

Usually people who write various frameworks know what they are doing and are experts in Scala. Frameworks such as [Akka](https://github.com/akka/akka) or [Play](https://github.com/playframework/Play20) are good examples of this. [Twitter's projects](https://github.com/twitter) are another.

Comment: In my experience much of the standard library is pretty imperative (presumably for performance reasons).

Comment: True, stdlib is sometimes very imperative. Nevertheless, there are some idiomatic patterns regarding style being followed there: class and a companion only per a file of a same name, using the cake-pattern to mix functionality together, combinator-style interface (parsers), etc.

Comment: IMO, stdlib and compiler are bad examples, since they aren't typical of what other programmers do in their everyday job.

Comment: And, besides what the others said, it contains lots of code that were written very long ago, and lots of code written by PhD students with not much Scala programming experience.